# Tooltip on Bing maps, what to use - Infobox, or something else?

Tags: fancybox, qtip, bing-maps

I'm working on a wepbage where I have a Bing map, along with pushpins. When clicking on pushpins, I am supposed to show a tooltip with custom content - something which would ideally be pulled out from the database through ajax.

This custom content is likely to contain youtube video, some html, as well as some buttons and links with specific actions.

My question is what to use to implement this? I see two potential solutions:

1. Something like [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/) or [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/): pros for this approach are that I am pretty familiar with either of these two, and that they can display virtually any content provided. Cons are that I may be having difficulties integrating the solution with the Bing maps (for example, when I move the map, I need to move the tooltip as well)
2. Infobox - as far as I know, regular part of Microsoft's api, well integrated with the maps. However, I have no idea how to fill Infobox with Ajax response. Moreover, I don't know how well Infobox can cope with rich html.

So, what to go for?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options. The first option is to us the built in infoboxes in Bing Maps by setting the htmlContent. I have a blog post on how to do this here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/simple-custom-infoboxes-in-bing-maps-v7/

The second method is to use the custom infobox module I created here: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Infobox%20Control